# Anonymous user redirected to core/install.php while admin does not

Tags: 8, database, redirection

As an admin I've built a large table on Drupal 8 (php, mysql).
It runs without issues for Admin, but trying as Anonymous user it redirects me to core/install.php

Since it's ONLY affecting Anonymous users, I suspect it's DRUPAL 8 that's setting the limit.
I want to find where Drupal does that. Anyone can give tips to the specific Drupal 8 files I can look into?

(Resist trying the
max_allowed_packet = 64M for my.cnf)
for the only reason that everything works flawlessly for the Admin side.

...when I shorten the table I've built, Anonymous users can see it an no redirects occur...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
max_allowed_packet indeed. Just raised to 8M and it was enough.

In my case steps taken as follows:

- Log in to PHPmyAdmin
- Go to tab "Variables"
- locate "max allowed packet"
- Click Edit
- Replace the current value with "8388608" (that's 8M)
- Click "Save"
- No need to restart - works immediately.